# Getting a star appearing after references header in Table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, bibtex

I am using the document class with bibtex and getting a unwanted star appearing as follows in my table of contents. Can anyone help? Following is what I have

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\settocbibname{References}
\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bib}
\nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You MWE does not show the cited behaviour. It produces rather nothing at all. I assume that your `bib` file contains something that outputs this star.